# get selection after PasteSpecial vba

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to copy data from a table and paste it into another sheet. When the new data is copied I want to create a new table of this data. I manage to copy the data to an another sheet, after it is copied the copied data stays selected. I thought I would create a new table by using the last command (in the code) and use the selection object to define the range but it throws an error every time. Is there something I'm missing?

```
    Dim oPrevSelection As range
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_48_04_AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results")
        Set oPrevSelection = Union(.ListColumns(1).range, .ListColumns(2).range)
        Union(.ListColumns(1).range, .ListColumns(2).range).Copy
    End With
    
    

    Sheets(asheet1).Select
    ActiveSheet.range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste colom in s range
    
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.range, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

```
Dim oPrevSelection As range
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("_48_04_AutoplaceCollisionsRobot_Results")
        Set oPrevSelection = Union(.ListColumns(1).range, .ListColumns(2).range)
        Union(.ListColumns(1).range, .ListColumns(2).range).Copy
    End With
    
    

    Sheets(asheet1).Select
    ActiveSheet.range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste colom in s range
    
    Dim r As range
    Set r = Selection
    
    r.Select
    
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, r, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
```